# Cast Datagrid.SelectedItems collection to List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, datagrid

I Have a class like this

```
public class Foo
{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

And a view model with a `List<Foo>`, this list is used as a `Bind` of one `DataGrid`, then in the codebehind I need to get the  `Datagrid.SelectedItems` collection and convert it to `List<Foo>`

Things that i tryed:

```
List<Foo> SelectedItemsList= (List<Foo>)DataGrid.SelectedItems;
// OR
object p = DataGrid.SelectedItems;
List<Foo> SelectedItemsList= ((IList)p).Cast<Foo>().ToList();
```

All this ways compile but throw an exception at run time.

What is the proper way to cast it ?

**NOTE:** Base Type of `DataGrid` is an `ObservableCollection` does this made some diference ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure to use the `System.Linq` namespace then :

You should be able to use :

```
List<Foo> SelectedItemsList = DataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<Foo>().ToList();
```

or if you're not quite sure what `DataGrid.SelectedItems` contains :

```
List<Foo> SelectedItemsList = DataGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<Foo>().ToList()
```

Comment: Not members ``OfType`` ``Cast`` found on ``DataGrid.SelectedItems`` any other Ideas ?

Comment: (Sorry to ask but...) Just to be absolutly sure, is the namespace "System.Linq" defined into your cs file?

Comment: Yes you have the reason, missing ``System.Linq``, I'm sorry now and tks.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it happens. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DataGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<Foo>().ToList()
```

Comment: Intellisense Don't show ``OfType`` as a member of  ``SelectedItems``

Comment: ``IList`` Is askingme for ``IList<T>``

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example i used to remove items when the user unselect an element in a ListBox.

```
var req = Listbox1.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToList().Where(c => c == item.Name).FirstOrDefault();
if (req==null)
{
    var a = MyMapView.Map.OperationalLayers.Where(c => c.Name == item.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    MyMapView.Map.OperationalLayers.Remove(a);
}
```